# HAProxy replace URL

Tags: regex, haproxy

i have domain with URL:

https://example.com/browse/TEST-1

i need in ha-proxy 2.0 change this URL to:

https://example.com/issue/TEST-1

i try:

```
http-request replace-path ^([^\ :]*)\ /browse/(.*) \1\ /issue/\2
http-request replace-path ^([^\ :]*)\ /browse/(.*)     \1\ /issue/\2
reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /browse/(.*)     \1\ /issue/\2
http-request replace-uri /browse/(.*) /issue/\1
http-request replace-path ^/browse/(.*) /issue/\1
```

I'm out of ideas, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to mess up with regex for this. I believe adding this on the haproxy.cfg file will do the job:

```
frontend http_front
   bind *:80
   bind *:443 ssl crt /path/to/ssl/certificate.pem

   acl is_test1 path_beg /browse/TEST-1

   http-request set-path /issue/TEST-1 if is_test1
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a reference.

This pattern will capture the elements, except for *"/browse/"*.

```
(.+?\/\/.+)\/.+\/(.+)
```

And, you can replace with,

```
\1/issue/\2
```